# Add value of checked check boxes in scroll div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and the user scrolls down or up the div follows.

http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/6adby/

When any Check Box is checked the value in the div should decrease by -1 , because the limit are 40.

(For this example, I changed the value for 3 because it's easier to check for 3 instead 40.)

Here is the code for check:

```
    $(':checkbox').click(function() {

            $("#limit").val(parseInt($("#limit").val()) -1);

            if ($("#limit").val() == "0")
                {
                alert("Ya has escogido las 3 canciones");
                }

    });
```

When the user unchecks a box I need to add +1 to first input, I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the checkbox value first to figure out if you should increase or decrease the counter like this:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    var delta = $(this).is(':checked') ? -1 : 1;

    if(delta < 0){
         $("#scroll").append( "<div>" + $(this).val()  + "</div>")
    }
    else{
        $("#scroll div:contains('" + $(this).val() + "')").remove();
    }

    $("#limit").val(parseInt($("#limit").val()) +  delta);

    if ($("#limit").val() == "0")
      {
         alert("Ya has escogido las 3 canciones");
      }

});
```

Comment: All right thanks for that, but how can I do for show the text(value) from check box in that div when has checked ?

Comment: Not sure I understand completely - do you want to keep a running tally of the checked items?  If so I updated my answer - you can try it out here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Nka79/